# Complex number: cube root of i

Tags: complex-numbers

I understand that the way to calculate the cube root of $i$ is to use Euler's formula and divide $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by $3$ and find $\frac{\pi}{6}$ on the complex plane; however, my question is why the following solution doesn't work.

So $(-i)^3 = i$, but why can I not cube root both sides and get $-i=(i)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Is there a rule where equality is not maintained when you root complex numbers or is there something else I am violating and not realizing?

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has $3$ cube roots. If you have one, the others can be obtained by multiplying by $e^{2\pi ik/3}$ for $k = 1,2$. So for this example, they are $e^{\pi i/6}, e^{5\pi i/6}, e^{3\pi i/2}$. Note that $e^{3\pi i/2} = -i$.

Answer (score 3):

There are three cube roots of $i$. The value at $e^{i\pi/6}$ is simply one of the roots. To find all of the roots, you can add $2\pi/3$ for each root to the angle of $\pi/6$. Since one root is at $\pi/6$, the next one will be at $\pi/6 + 2\pi/3 = 5\pi/6$. The next one will be at $5\pi/6 + 2\pi/3 = 3\pi/2$. With this last angle, the root is exactly $-i$.

In other words, given one of the roots at angle $\theta_0$, all of them are $e^{i(\theta_0+2n\pi/3)}$, where $n$ goes through $0, 1, 2$.

Comment: Why would we use 2*pi/3 specifically? How would I be able to find the solutions for other roots?

Comment: Because it is cube roots, it is $2\pi/3$. If it was fourth roots, it would be $2\pi/4$. If it was the $n$th roots, it would be $2\pi/n$.

Comment: Is there a proof that you could link me to? I am curious as to how it works. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is a direct result of [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Answer (score 3):

$-i$ is certainly one of the cube roots of $i$ but it is certainly not the only one.

Every complex number (except $0$) has three cube roots.

A quicker way to find these roots is to use the cube roots of unity, which can be written $1, \omega, \omega^2$ and multiply them successively by the root you've already got.

So in your case, the three roots are $-i, - \omega i =\frac{\sqrt3}{2} + \frac 12 i, - \omega^2 i = -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} + \frac 12 i$